# Clicks and earnings reported in Google Adsense that go away next login

Tags: google-adsense

I have a Google AdSense account. From the last couple of weeks I have been seeing some unusual activity. A certain day it showed 4 clicks and estimated earning jumped accordingly.

After some minutes when I logged into again, it strangely showed only 1 click and the earnings dropped. It occurred twice so far and its confusing me badly.

Comment: Adsense is an unusual beast to me too. I could suggest that your ads are too close to the content your users want to read, or you're just not following adsense policies.

Comment: Google takes away clicks/earnings that it determines are made artificially or inappropriately. You may have some kind of regular bot or something else that causes problems.

Comment: Please rephrase it as a question, so we could answer.